# Mysql : Check duplicate value of a column in 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Situation : 3 tables (with completely different columns type/number) with only a column which must be unique among the 3 tables (example, column **address**).

So, when i insert a new record in one of the 3 tables i have to check if the value **address** it is not already used in any of the 3 tables

Table1

```
id | column1 | column2 | address |
--------------------------------
1  | ...     | ...     | 1       |
2  | ...     | ...     | 2       |
2  | ...     | ...     | 5       |
```

Table2

```
id | column1 | address |
------------------------
1  | ...     | 3       |
2  | ...     | 4       |
2  | ...     | 10      |
```

Table3

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3 | address |
--------------------------------------------
1  | ...     | ...     | ...     | 15      |
2  | ...     | ...     | ...     | 16      |
2  | ...     | ...     | ...     | 17      |
```

To do this check, i used this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( a.address ) AS cont1, (SELECT COUNT( b.address ) FROM testtabella2 AS b WHERE b.address =  '1' LIMIT 1) AS cont2, (SELECT COUNT( c.address ) FROM testtabella3 AS c WHERE c.address =  '1' LIMIT 1) AS cont3
```

FROM testtabella1 AS a WHERE a.address =  '1' LIMIT 1

Example: if MYNEWADDRESS = 1

[image]

In this way if one of the 3 counts is equal to 1 it means that MYNEWADDRESS it's already used.

It's possibile to do something more optimized? UNION , JOIN ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a very poor data design.  You should have a single table for addresses with a unique constraint on that table.  That said, the most efficient method would be to define a unique constraint on each table and then do:

```
select (exists (select 1 from table1 t where t.address = 1) or
        exists (select 1 from table2 t where t.address = 1) or
        exists (select 1 from table3 t where t.address = 1) 
       ) as already_exists_flag
```

Comment: The column address is UNIQUE in the 3 tables

Comment: @Whiteboard . . . If the columns are defined as `unique` then you have a unique index.